# How could I use jQuery and batch add a class (class="none") to "tr" when this "tr" has attribute valign="baseline"

Tags: jquery

How could I use jQuery and batch add a class (class="none") to "tr" when this "tr" has attribute `valign="baseline"`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="table-form">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">ID:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ID']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Cid:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['cid'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Text:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['text'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Star:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="star" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['star'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update record"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How could I use jQuery and batch add a class (class="none") to "tr" when this "tr" has attribute `valign="baseline"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [**attribute equals selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select all `tr` elements that have a `valign` attribute set to `baseline`:

```
$("tr[valign='baseline']").addClass("none");
```